# facing OS error trying to download the model in openLLM

Tags: gpu, large-language-model, safe-tensors

I am trying to run the openLLM but i am facing this error.
I ran 3 commands.

1. !pip3 install openllm
2. !openllm -h
3. !openllm start opt

but the 3rd commands output is generating this error

> OSError:  model.safetensors or model.safetensors.index.json and thus cannot be loaded with `safetensors`. Please make sure that the model has been saved with `safe_serialization=True` or do not set `use_safetensors=True`.[text](https://stackoverflow.com)

trying to run OPENllm faced an OS error